# Ignore store submissions testers data in google analytics

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, google-analytics

I'm working on a new flutter application which I've just published to the Google play and app store so I don't have a lot of active users.
Each time I published a new version to the stores, there are a lot of automatic/manual validations which shows a lot of new users and a lot of "unreal" events in google analytics.
As a result, during these days it is very hard to track my "real" users usage.

I wonder if there is a way to filter out all google/apple users usage so I won't see their data in GA. I saw that there are some filters that can be defined in GA but I'm not sure if it can help and what should I filter.